# Que erro é esse ao rodar 'php artisan migrate'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Olá,
Criei uma aplicação com laravel 5.7 e ao rodar php artisan migrate mostra esse erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que significa esse erro e como corrigir?

Segue meu database.php

```
<?php

 return [


'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8_bin',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
?>
```

Comment: Já existe o banco ?

Comment: Sim, já criei... Só não tem tabelas!